# Can I create a Request object by a URL?

Tags: c#, .net, request, query-string

I have a URL, such as `http://www.mydomain.com/?param1=asd2&param2=asd2`.
I'd like to create a sort of Frequest object, so than I can easily do somethings like:

```
Request.Querystring("param1")
```

without do a further `Split` and access to the array. Can I?

Comment: "Can I?" Sure, go ahead. You have our approval.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for? It isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Are you looking something like this?

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/?param1=asd2&param2=asd2");
var nv = uri.ParseQueryString();
Console.WriteLine(nv["param1"]);
```

**EDIT**

It seams one of my referenced libraries implemented this *extension Method*. Anyway, it can be done as

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/?param1=asd2&param2=asd2");
var nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
Console.WriteLine(nv["param1"]);
```

Comment: Yes, it is what I'm looking for. But seems that I don't have `ParseQueryString`...

Comment: @markzzz you should use `System.Net.Http` namespace

Comment: Oh that's perfect! And what if I have only `param1=asd2&param2=asd2` as string?

Comment: @markzzz then `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` is enough. No need for `Uri` class.